# Pushforward along an exponential map

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

My differential geometry is a bit rusty, so I'd like some help with what follows:

I have the following setting: $M,N$ Riemannian manifold of dimension $m<n$ with codimension $d$, $M$ in embedded in $N$ via an isometry $\phi$. We define a new manifold $\mathcal{T}=M\times B^d\ni(p,x)$ and a map:
$$\begin{array}{rclc}\overline\phi:&\mathcal{T}&\longrightarrow&N\\&(p,x)&\longmapsto&\exp_{\phi(p)}x\end{array}$$
Assume this new map is again an embedding. Take a vector:
$$v=(v_M,v_B)\in T_{(p,x)}\mathcal{T}\cong T_pM\times T_xB^d$$
I would like to know what is:
$$\overline\phi_*v\in TN$$
We are taking the pushforward of an exponential map, so intuitively I would say that it is just the parallel transport of $\overline\phi_*v$, where $v$ is now seen as an element of $T_{(p,0)}\mathcal{T}$, along the geodesic $\gamma(t)=\exp_{\phi(p)}(tx)$.

Is this correct? If it is, what would be the easiest way to prove it? If not so, is there a nice expression/interpretation for it?

---

**Edit:** Some details on the definition of $\overline\phi$. As written above, the map doesn't really make sense, because $\exp_{\phi(p)}$ should take an element of $T_\phi(p)N$ as argument, while $x\in B^d$ (thanks Jack Lee). However, assuming $M$ is orientable, we have a natural identification of $\mathcal{T}$ as a submanifold of $NM$ (the normal bundle to $M$ in $N$; fix a basis of $NM$...), in particular we can see $(p,x)$ as an element of $N_{\phi(p)}M\subset T_{\phi(p)}M$.

Comment: Unfortunately, your map doesn't make sense they way you've written it. The exponential map $\exp_{\phi(p)}$ acts on elements of $T_{\phi(p)}N$, not on elements of $B^d$. Instead, the domain of $\overline\phi$ should be the normal bundle of $\phi(M)$ in $N$.

Comment: @JackLee Yeah, sorry about that. I forgot to mention that we can identify $M\times B^d$ with a subset of $NM$ (the normal bundle of $M$), and that we have in a natural way: $T_{(p,x)}\mathcal{T}\cong T_pM\times T_xB^d$. Assuming these identifications the maps should make sense. I will add those details to the question.

Comment: That still doesn't work. You need to assume that the normal bundle of $M$ is trivial. Just assuming that $M$ is orientable isn't enough (unless $d=1$ and $N$ is also orientable).

Comment: @JackLee Sorry, as I said, my differential geometry is a bit rusty... Well in that case, take my definition to be local (the induced metric should agree on the intersection of the charts, right?) and if this doesn't work either, then simply assume that $NM$ is trivial.